# How to update polymer element attribute from dart code

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to learn dart and polymer. Here repository that I try to learn on:

https://bitbucket.org/romanoff/polymer_sample

When I try to set attribute from dart code of one custom element to other custom element, it doesn't seem to work. Here is line where I try to do this:
https://bitbucket.org/romanoff/polymer_sample/src/f8314627fe8eee9f6fde58c300acf081b396f927/web/clickcounter/clickcounter.dart?at=master#cl-33

Have also tried following options:

 `var timer = $['timer'].xtag;
 timer.textValue = 'Text value set form attached handler';`

`var timer = $['timer'];
 timer.setAttribute('textValue', 'Text value set form attached handler');`

Comment: How does your whole HTML Structure look like? Can you post a full example? You can set attributes like in normal HTML. $... indicates that you are using the shadowdom. this also means that you nest the objects? Why do you want to set textValue?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

```dart
$['timer'].attributes['textValue'] = 'Text value set form attached handler';
```

or

```dart
import 'path_to_dart_file_containing_timer_component#;

...

($['timer'] as MyTimer).textValue = 'Text value set form attached handler';
```

where `MyTimer` is the name of the class of your timer element
and your timer component class has a field

```dart
@published String textValue;
```

Comment: First option worked just fine. Second one failed. Here is error: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'CustomTimer' in type cast

Comment: This indicates that your Polymer is not upgraded (not properly initialized). Maybe you are missing the import for your element in HTML or the import is invalid or some other problem with Polymer initialization. `.attributes['textValue'] = ...` works with every element.